# What does the "/" in php require/include mean?

Tags: php

When I use `require("/toinclude.php")`, what does the "/" mean?

- Is it the root dir of my ubuntu?
- or is it the www directory apacheset for me?
- or is it the path of current file? this seems to be true...

What's more, I really get confused by the use of path in PHP. Is it so that the "/" in `require()`/`include()` means the current directory, the "/" in `system(...)`/`exec(...)` is 
the root directory of Linux, and the "/" in html code `<form action="/processpost.php">` is the "www" directory Apache set for me?

Comment: I think it's www root. But I don't know a thing about php or apache :)

Comment: Did you try it yourself? Enable error reporting and try with and without an `/` and the error messages will tell you exactly what means what.

Comment: / means the absolutely root of the filesystem, your webpage is placed somewhere /var/www or /home/something/public_html/ etc.etc.

Comment: @GipszJakab if "/" means the root of filesystem, then how is it possible that I could simply use require("/toinc.php") while there is no php files in root directory?

Answer (score 2):

In PHP (which is server side), any path that starts with `/` (at least on Unix-based systems) is the filesystem root. In most (if not all) cases, this is *not* what you want.

In HTML (which is client side), '/' is the URL root. That is: it is placed directly after the domain name. E.g. `/process.php` in a HTML file fetched from `http://example.com` will redirect to `http://example.com/process.php`. This *could* be the www-root, but might also be something else depending on settings in the server.

`include` and `require` use an include path to get files. If you do not provide a full path (that is, you omit the `/` at the beginning`), PHP will scan all directories it finds in its include path, starting in the current directory. Often, the path to PEAR modules is in that path, so code like this:

```
include("SomePearModule/Module.class.php");
```

works, even though it is not in your website's tree.

More can be found in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

Answer (score 1):

It's the literal server-side (file system) path. Well, not *always* literal.

It depends on your server setup. If PHP is running in a jailed [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot), then `/` as far as PHP sees it might actually be something like `/var/web/chroots/domain.com/` or similar.

Most often, you want some kind of configuration file that figures out where libraries and stuff are, based on relative paths of where the script is actually executing, then pass that information to `require()` and `require_once()` respectively.

Something like:

```
<?php

$base = dirname(__FILE__);
$Libraries = $base . '/libraries';

require_once($Libraries . '/Library.php');
?>
```

If you use any kind of modern framework, this is generally handled for you by whatever means it provides to load things. It's good to just make sure that any calls to `require()` or `require_once()` don't have to change depending on where you install the app, it's all relative to where it's executed.